# click checkbox in listgrid record

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

i am using SmartGWT , i have a listGrid with `RecordClickHandler`  and each record contains a checkBox,

when i click the checkBox the `RecordClickHandler` is apply , but this is not the behavior that i want,

i want the check box to have a defferent behaviur than the record it self so can any one provide any help please ?

onRecordClick body :

```
    public void onRecordClick(RecordClickEvent event) {
    final int recordNumber = event.getRecordNum();
    if(selectedJob == recordNumber) return;
    boolean changeSelectedEquipment = true;
    if(ClientFactoryImpl.isDirty()){
        int tabNum = jobsContentView.getJobTabSet().getSelectedTabNumber();
        switch (tabNum) {
        case 0:
            if(!jobsContentView.getJobsDetailsView().isValid()){
                event.cancel();
                changeSelectedEquipment = false;
                dropBoxWindowManager.showError(jobsViewVocabularies.unableToSave());
                jobsContentView.getJobTabSet().showErrorOnTab(tabNum, jobsViewVocabularies.unableToSave());
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if(!jobsContentView.getJobsEquipmentUsedView().isValid()){
                event.cancel();
                changeSelectedEquipment = false;
                dropBoxWindowManager.showError(jobsViewVocabularies.unableToSave());
                jobsContentView.getJobTabSet().showErrorOnTab(tabNum, jobsViewVocabularies.unableToSave());
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    if(changeSelectedEquipment && ClientFactoryImpl.isDirty()){
        clientFactory.getJobsView().saveJobsView(null ,REDIRECTION_PLACE.TAB_CACHED, (((ListDataRow)(jobListGrid.getRecord(selectedJob))).getJobDetails().getJob().getJobId()));
        ((ListDataRow)jobListGrid.getRecord(selectedJob)).setIsCached(false);
    }
    if(changeSelectedEquipment){
        updateNewRecord(recordNumber);
    } else {
        jobListGrid.deselectRecord(recordNumber);
        jobListGrid.selectRecord(selectedJob);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the _different_ behavior that you want to apply and the default behavior that you don't want to apply?

Comment: @RAS it is all the same behavior , when i click on the check box i want different behavior than when i click on the rest of the row

Comment: @RAS i described more in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041725/smartgwt-listgrid-checkbox-selection

Comment: Yes I understood your point.. & what you're trying to achieve is possible too.. But unfortunately right now I'm not working on SmartGWT and so unable to make a sample code to share with you.